# How to get the id from a dummyapi post?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios, react-query

Please keep in mind that i'm new working with api's, also sorry for the bad english that's not my native language.

Here is my problem, i use axios to get posts from dummyapi, i have the api key, i get the object in a data variable, then that's how i try to access my data in my return:

```js
{Object.keys(data.data.data).map((e) => <p>{e}</p>)}
```

it give me a list of number, i suppose i should be able to access a data from the post by using something like :

```js
{Object.keys(data.data.data).map((e) => <p>{e.id}</p>)}
```

but i can't, please tell me where is my error, again i'm new working with api's

the api endpoint is : https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post

Comment: what's your Api endpoint?

Comment: @KomailFayazbakhsh the api endpoint is https://dummyapi.io/data/v1/post

Comment: it returns this error, "error": "APP_ID_MISSING"

Comment: @KomailFayazbakhsh yeah you need to create an account and get a key to use the api

Comment: you can use this approach.
const ids = res.data.map(item=> <p>item.id</p>).
and in your JSX codes,
return(<>{ids}</>)